# How to dispaly diffrent background color each page with Angular 5?

Tags: html, angular, css

I am new to Angular, I need to change the `background-color` of the body tag. I created a project in Angular with multiple pages.

**Ex:**

```
Login / Home / About / Service / Contact
```

I need to display a different `background-color` on each page.

But here actually, the body tag is common for all pages so I'm unable to change the `background-color in CSS?

Comment: use `!important` and override in pages, it should work .

Comment: Or becames all your pages as < div class="container" [style.backgorund-color]="myColor" > <myColor is a variable of each component

Answer (score 1):

you could try changing it during the Component `ngOnInit` lifecycle,
something like this

```
ngOnInit(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

inside your component code

Or you could also try changing `ViewEncapsulation`, but it will change it for all the component styles, so it could lend you to unexpected things.

Something like this

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-theme",
    templateUrl: "./theme.component.html",
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styleUrls: ['./theme.component.scss']
})
```

As you asked in your comment, you want to edit body classes as well, so I think you're going for the first option I wrote.

It could be different based on how many classes you want to handle. I'll write down the example for just one class

```
ngOnInit(){
  const body = document.body;
  body.className = '';
  body.classList.add('classname');
}
```

If you need to handle more classes, you will need to edit your code, to remove just the classes you don't need, instead of all of them

Comment: Thanks for your quick  answer
i want to add class inside body tag for changing each component 

Like : 

Login page html tag <body class="login">
home page html tag <body class="home">

Comment: @jayaprakash I will edit the answer in a few minutes

Comment: yes i tried  you updated answer it's working fine but class not removed changing another component

i  assigned class[login_bg] for login component it working fine after i signin it's moving into next component  home but still [login_bg] into body tag. no need login_bg in home component i have multiple component each component can remove previous class  login_bg ?

Comment: @jayaprakash I've tested my example right now and it works. Are you sure that you're loading components with the right order?